# using own DNS server - how to configure

Tags: dns, web-hosting, vps, nameservers, ovh

Currently I own a new VPS server and running my websites. For example I own www.auraquotes.com and that is running in this VPS server.

Currently I have issues with my hosting provider and I have switched to ovh unmanaged service provider. As the name 'unmanaged service provider' they will just help me in giving physical machines and that is all they will help.

how will I setup DNS server in my new VPS machine and adjust the nameserver settings appropriately?
Venkat.

Answer (score 1):

DNS is a complicated service to set up and run, it is far easier to use an online DNS service, who will give you a nice web front end to configure things with.

The process is largely similar though, you need to configure your domain registrar with the name of your DNS server, or your DNS provider.

From there you configure the records you need and everything should work!